# Using numpy to vectorize subtraction of array with scalar (via another array) without using double for-loop

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, for-loop, vector, vectorization

Suppose one wanted to use `numpy` to vectorize array subtractions. As an example, consider the following setup (code below): I am computing the [euclidean distance](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/795b967db2917cdde7c2da2d1ee327eb673276c0) between some (x,y) points with a given centroid. The reason for this question is that the example code below works for exactly 2-dimensions (`x` and `y`), but I would like to generalize and adapt this operation to N-dimensions for the purposes of adapting my [k-means algorithm](https://github.com/allthemikeysaretaken/Vector-Quantization/blob/master/vector_quantization.py). The code below is only to compute the error given a specified centroid.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(10) ## for reproducibility
x = np.random.normal(40, 10, 10)
y = np.random.normal(50, 10, 10)
data = np.array([x, y])

centroids = np.array([[25, 75], [45, 55], [20, 80], [40, 60]])
k = len(centroids)
print("\nDATA:\n{}\n\n{} CENTROIDS:\n{}\n".format(data, k, centroids))
partials = np.array([[(data[i] - centroid[i])**2 for i in range(len(data))] for centroid in centroids])
res = np.sqrt(np.sum(partials))
print("\nPARTIAL DISTANCES:\n{}\n\nTOTAL DISTANCE:\n{}\n".format(partials, res))
```

Running the code above produces the following output:

```
DATA:
[[53.31586504 47.15278974 24.54599708 39.9161615  46.21335974 32.79914439
  42.65511586 41.08548526 40.04291431 38.25399789]
 [54.3302619  62.03037374 40.34934329 60.28274078 52.2863013  54.45137613
  38.63397788 51.35136878 64.84537002 39.20195114]]

4 CENTROIDS:
[[25 75]
 [45 55]
 [20 80]
 [40 60]]


PARTIAL DISTANCES:
[[[8.01788213e+02 4.90746093e+02 2.06118652e-01 2.22491874e+02
   4.50006631e+02 6.08266533e+01 3.11703116e+02 2.58742836e+02
   2.26289271e+02 1.75668460e+02]
  [4.27238073e+02 1.68211205e+02 1.20066801e+03 2.16597719e+02
   5.15912109e+02 4.22245943e+02 1.32248756e+03 5.59257758e+02
   1.03116510e+02 1.28150030e+03]]

 [[6.91536114e+01 4.63450368e+00 4.18366235e+02 2.58454139e+01
   1.47224186e+00 1.48860878e+02 5.49848164e+00 1.53234257e+01
   2.45726985e+01 4.55085444e+01]
  [4.48549123e-01 4.94261549e+01 2.14641742e+02 2.79073501e+01
   7.36416063e+00 3.00988153e-01 2.67846680e+02 1.33125097e+01
   9.69313108e+01 2.49578348e+02]]

 [[1.10994686e+03 7.37273991e+02 2.06660894e+01 3.96653489e+02
   6.87140229e+02 1.63818097e+02 5.13254274e+02 4.44597689e+02
   4.01718414e+02 3.33208439e+02]
  [6.58935454e+02 3.22907468e+02 1.57217458e+03 3.88770311e+02
   7.68049096e+02 6.52732182e+02 1.71114779e+03 8.20744071e+02
   2.29662810e+02 1.66448079e+03]]

 [[1.77312262e+02 5.11624011e+01 2.38826206e+02 7.02889396e-03
   3.86058392e+01 5.18523215e+01 7.04964021e+00 1.17827824e+00
   1.84163795e-03 3.04852335e+00]
  [3.21459301e+01 4.12241752e+00 3.86148309e+02 7.99423486e-02
   5.95011476e+01 3.07872269e+01 4.56506901e+02 7.47988219e+01
   2.34776106e+01 4.32558836e+02]]]

TOTAL DISTANCE:
163.00230640508593
```

I am using a nested double for-loop in this code. I noticed `numpy.subtract` does not have an `axis` kwarg. I was thinking I could `numpy.tile` the centroids to perform the subtraction, but this seems inefficient for large N, especially if many iterations are needed to converge. Is there a different way to vectorize this operation?

Comment: So `data` is (2,10) shape, `centroids` (4,2), and `partials` (4,2,10).  If `centroids` is expanded to (4,2,1), then broadcasting takes care of the rest.

Comment: `data - centroids[:,:,None]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `expand_dims` to create the missing axis:

```
partials = (data.T - np.expand_dims(centroids, axis=1))**2
```

That way `data.T` has shape `(10,2)` and you subtract from it an array with shape `(4,1,2)` so the subtraction is broadcast across the second axis of this array.

You can also do this by adding an extra axis on the end of `centroids` and not transposing `data:

```
partials = (data - centroids[:,:,np.newaxis])**2
```